# How to flatten out nested list into one list more efficiently instead of using unlist method?

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-lists, flatten

I have a nested list which contains set of data.frame objects in it, now I want them flatten out. I used most common approach like unlist method, it is not properly fatten out my list, the output was not well represented. How can I make this happen more efficiently? Does anyone knows any trick of doing this operation? Thanks.

## example:

```
mylist <- list(pass=list(Alpha.df1_yes=airquality[2:4,], Alpha.df2_yes=airquality[3:6,],Alpha.df3_yes=airquality[2:5,],Alpha.df4_yes=airquality[7:9,]),
             fail=list(Alpha.df1_no=airquality[5:7,], Alpha.df2_no=airquality[8:10,],  Alpha.df3_no=airquality[13:16,],Alpha.df4_no=airquality[11:13,]))
```

I tried like this, it works but output was not properly arranged.

```
res <- lapply(mylist, unlist)
```

after flatten out, I would like to do merge them without duplication:

```
out <- lapply(res, rbind.data.frame)
```

## my desired output:

```
mylist[[1]]$pass:
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
```

How can make this sort of flatten output more compatibly represented? Can anyone propose possible idea of doing this in R? Thanks a lot.

Comment: something like `do.call(rbind, unlist(mylist, FALSE))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lapply and duplicated:

```
res <- lapply(mylist, function(i){
  x <- do.call(rbind, i)
  x[ !duplicated(x), ]
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x
})

res$pass
#    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1     36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 2     12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 3     18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 4     12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 5     18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 6     NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 7     28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
# 8     36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 9     12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 10    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 11    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 12    23     299  8.6   65     5   7
# 13    19      99 13.8   59     5   8
# 14     8      19 20.1   61     5   9
```

Above still returns a list, if we want to keep all in one dataframe with no lists, then:

```
res <- do.call(rbind, unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE))
res <- res[!duplicated(res), ]
res
#                      Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# pass.Alpha.df1_yes.2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# pass.Alpha.df1_yes.3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# pass.Alpha.df1_yes.4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# pass.Alpha.df2_yes.5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# pass.Alpha.df2_yes.6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
# pass.Alpha.df4_yes.7    23     299  8.6   65     5   7
# pass.Alpha.df4_yes.8    19      99 13.8   59     5   8
# pass.Alpha.df4_yes.9     8      19 20.1   61     5   9
# fail.Alpha.df2_no.10    NA     194  8.6   69     5  10
# fail.Alpha.df3_no.13    11     290  9.2   66     5  13
# fail.Alpha.df3_no.14    14     274 10.9   68     5  14
# fail.Alpha.df3_no.15    18      65 13.2   58     5  15
# fail.Alpha.df3_no.16    14     334 11.5   64     5  16
# fail.Alpha.df4_no.11     7      NA  6.9   74     5  11
# fail.Alpha.df4_no.12    16     256  9.7   69     5  12
```